# Is it possible to wrap an Angular app and monitor user activity?

Tags: angular, monitoring, angular-directive

I'm wondering is it possible to wrap an Angular app as a whole `<Component/>` with a `<div>` and listen to the user activates? Something like:

```
<div
   mouseEnter = helper()
   mouseOut = helper()
   keyDown = helper()
   scroll = helper()
   ...
>
   <Component/>
</div>
```

And the `helper()` method is to constantly calculate the user active engagement time.
If not possible, how to listen to all user activities on an Angular app? Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: Angular isn't special in this regard. It is just plain JS/HTML/CSS at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is gauge engagement, why not use window event listeners for the different input methods?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm trying to create a library and pass the app as a component to my library, then gauge the engagement. Is that possible? Then I can install this library on different apps.